# Beginner python project on school managment system?

Tags: python

i am beginner in programming and just got the hang of python language.i am doing a small project on a miniature school management system using the class defined below.i need help in reading and writing these details into a csv file.i also want to know how to modify these details.i hope you would help me with this in python language itself.

```
class student:

 def __init__ (self):
  self.adno=0
  self.name="null"
  self.m = [0,0,0,0,0]
  self.m[0]=0
  self.m[1]=0
  self.m[2]=0
  self.m[3]=0
  self.m[4]=0
 def inp(self):
  print "Enter the details:\n"
  self.appno=input("Enter the application number   :")
  self.name=raw_input("Enter the name                 :")
  print "\nEnter the mark for  \n"
  self.m[0]=input("English         : ")
  self.m[1]=input("Mathematics     : ")
  self.m[2]=input("chemistry       : ")
  self.m[3]=input("Physics         : ")
  self.m[4]=input("computer science: ")
 def out(self):
  print "\nApplication number :%d\nName :%s\n"  %(self.appno,self.name)
  print "\nMarks : \n\n"
  print "English        :  ",self.m[0]
  print "Mathematics    :  ",self.m[1]
  print "Science        :  ",self.m[2]
  print "Social Science :  ",self.m[3]
  print "Second Language:  ",self.m[4]
```

Comment: It's not really clear what exactly you're asking; what's the problem, and what have you tried to do to solve it? We won't just modify your code to make it save to a CSV file.

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: how to read and write these details into a csv text file.

Comment: Take a look at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html. Or, if you really want to start out with Python 2.7, at https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html

Comment: as i said before i am beginner i didnt quite understand the link content please would u make it simpler by coding the above program so that the datas are stored in  a TEXT file

Comment: No, we aren't here to do your homework for you.

Comment: this is not a homework but i really want to learn the concepts of files in python

Comment: We don't do tutorials either. I suggest you take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then look up an actual tutorial: http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using csv files, you can also use **Pickle**

Saving a student:

```
import pickle

file = open("student_record.pkl", "w")
pickle.dump(file, student_object)
file.close()
```

Loading a student's record:

```
import pickle

file = open("student_record.pkl")
student_object = pickle.load(file)
```

You can also save multiple student classes in one file by putting a list into pickle.dump().